# set default Font for NSTextView with swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, fonts, nstextview

I am able to change the Font in NSTextView AFTER I have loaded some text.

- nameTextView.string = "Some Text"
- nameTextView.textStorage?.font = NSFont(name: "Lucida Sans", size: 15)

but how can I set this Font as the default Font?

if the user starts typing in an empty NsTextView control, the Font always returns to the controls default Font which seems to be 'Helvetica Regular', size 12

Answer (score 15):

Ok, after a lot of try and error I found a solution:

```html
let font = NSFont(name: "Lucida Sans", size: 18)
let attributes = NSDictionary(object: font!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
        
nameTextView.typingAttributes = attributes
```

I put that code lines in function awakefromNib

Comment: Font is an optional because a particular font may not exist on the system.  Best to use `if let font = NSFont(name: "Lucida Sans", size: 18) { let attributes = NSDictionary(object: font, forKey: NSFontAttributeName) \n        nameTextView.typingAttributes = attributes }`   I learned this the hard way today because my development machine had the Consolas font but that's not a default font on the Mac.

Answer (score 10):

The following works for me

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    nameTextView.font = NSFont(name: "Lucida Sans", size: 15)
```